# How translate permutation operator from Lotus Formula to Lotus Script?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I have to translate some 20 years old code from Lotus Formula to Lotus Script. The original code contains some premutation operator, which I don't think are implemented in Lotus Script.

Here is one of the line I have to translate.

```
@If(Transport *= "Car" : "Bus" : "Boat" | (Transport *= "Airplane" & someOtherCondition); doSomething; doSomethingElse)
```

I know I can translate `Transport *= "Airplane"` by `doc.getFirstItem("Transport").Contains("Airplane")`, but what stand for `Transport *= "Car" : "Bus" : "Boat"` ?

I don't want to use the Evaluate function, I will only use it if I don't have any other choices.

Here is a [link](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/2a483322f7b71a4485256c54004bde56?OpenDocument) to Permutation operator official documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List1 *= List2
```

`*=` compares *every* element from List1 with *every* element from List2. If there is at least one match then it returns @True.

```
List1 = List2
```

`=` compares pairwise: *first* element from List1 with *first* element from List2, *second* element from List1 with *second* element from List2, and so on. If one list has fewer elements than the other, the last element in the shorter list will be used for comparison with remaining elements of the longer list. If there is at least one match then it returns @True.

`*=` is different from `=` only if you have lists on both sides.

Your formula

```
@If(Transport *= "Car" : "Bus" : "Boat"; ...
```

can be "translated" to

```
set item = doc.getFirstItem("Transport")
If item.Contains("Car") Or item.Contains("Bus") Or item.Contains("Boat") Then
    ...
```

Yet, don't hesitate to use `Evaluate` in LotusScript: it's fast and reliable.

Comment: Are we sure that Transport isn't ever a list?